# Laravel 4 form redirect fails

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am stuck with something. I'm trying to get a form to work, but for now all I want is to redirect to a page when the submit button is pressed. The problem is that the same login page is reloading and no redirect happens. Please help.

The route file:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'LoginController@showLogin'));
Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'LoginController@doLogin'));

Route::get('hr', function() {
    return View::make('hr', array('page_title' => 'HR Area'));
});
```

The login controller:

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function showLogin()
    {
        return View::make('login', array('page_title' => 'Log in to MANGER'));
    }


    public function doLogin()
    {
        echo "Success!";
    }
}
```

Here's the login form:

```
    <!-- The login view -->

<html>

<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}

    <style type="text/css">

    #heading {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-top: 50px;
        color: #323875;
    }

    #login-form {
        margin-left: 350px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    #login-form td {
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #other-links {
        color: blue;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
        {{ HTML::image('images/bb_logo.png'); }}
    </div>

    <div id="heading">MANGER Login</div>

    <div id="login-form">
        <?php
        //build the form

        echo Form::open(array('url' => '/'));

        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr>';
            //enter boring brands email id
            echo '<td>';
            echo Form::label('email', 'Email ID');
            echo '</td>';

            echo '<td>';
            echo Form::text('email', '');
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';    
            //enter password
            echo '<td>';
                echo Form::label('password', 'Password');
            echo '</td>';

            echo '<td>';
                echo Form::password('password');
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '</table>';

        echo '<br/><br/>';

        //the submit button
        echo Form::submit('Log in');

        echo Form::close();
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="other-links">
        Forgot password | Register
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        MANGER &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'LoginController@showLogin'));
Route::post('manger/public/hr', array('uses' => 'LoginController@doLogin'));

Route::get('hr', function() {
    return View::make('hr', array('page_title' => 'HR Area'));
});

Route::get('employee', function() {
    return View::make('employee', array('page_title' => 'Employee Area'));
});
```

filters.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

/*Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: Can we see the whole code for the form?

Comment: @Raphael_ Posted in the original question.

Comment: Oh boy, you should really take a look at [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#blade-templating).

Comment: @Raphael_ I did start with blade, but am really new and got confused as to how to plan sidebars, etc., especially what they might change from page to page. You think this has got something to do with Blade?

Comment: Nope, it's just that this is plain ugly (no offenses meant). Did you try reducing your problem? Like, deleting all that bloat HTML and replacing it all with only a static form, like `<html><body><form action="/" method="post"><input type="submit"></form></body></html>`. And if that works, slowly build towards your full problem so that you can know exactly what is giving you trobules?

Comment: @Raphael_ LOL. I knew when I started coding how ugly this looks, so no offense taken. :-) I intend to use Blade (and all the other nice features of Laravel) but I have to get this up in a few days and I'm racing against time. Will try what you have suggested and report. I take it, then, then the routing and all I've used is fine?

Comment: Did what you said, and funnily, it now redirects me to localhost/xampp
What do I do now? O.O

Comment: Well, ideally, you would `return 'Success';` instead of `echo`ing, on the controller. But ye, other than that, it seems okey.

Comment: What's the full address of your website? Locally, I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62892/discussion-between-raphael-and-dotslash).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'post'))
```

Along with:

```
public function doLogin()
{
     return Redirect::to('your/page');
}
```

Comment: Not working. I feel like there's some problem with my redirects. I set up the Bitnami LAMP server on Ubuntu 14.04. Just to test things, I wrote `return Redirect::to('sdsdsdasfa');` and I'm still on the login page. :(

Comment: Is there any check on permissions yet? Post your routes.

Comment: Do you mean file permissions? I've added routes.php to my post.

Comment: I meant. is there any route filter? Just to make sure you are not just getting redirected back to the login page after the first redirect.

Comment: I don't remember setting up any routes filter. Could you please see my routes.php file in the original post and see if it's all right.

Comment: take a look in aqpp/filters.php

Comment: Very interesting! I found this in filters.php: `Route::filter('guest', function()
{
 if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});`
Is this the culprit? And if so, does that mean I have no option but to use Auth component like used in the official tutorials?

Comment: Much probably yes. Try to remove it just to test the differences. Then put it back and try to understand why the user does not get properly authenticated.

Comment: I commented it out by still the same thing is happening. 
:( I've added filters.php to my question as well.